# Does Google BigQuery support jsonb as data type?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are thinking move from PostgreSql to Google BigQuery. PostGresql support Jsonb as a data type. Can someone tell me does BigQuery also support that type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about [supported data types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) in the documentation. There is no `jsonb` type, but you may be interested in the [related feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69949409) for a JSON type, which has some workarounds.